# Where to call ASP.Net HTTP2 PushPromise

Tags: c#, asp.net, http2

We're migrating our ASP.Net (4.6) Web Forms website to a shiny new 2016 Server and as part of that we're keen to make the most out of the new HTTP2 possibilities. Part of that is using Server Push to get css and js files to the client as quickly as possible. However, having found basically *zero* documentation around this online (please correct me if I'm wrong) I'm struggling to check the best place to call the HttpResponse.PushPromise() method.

On a standard page I'm assuming this would just sit in Page_Load()? However, most pages in this project actually derive from a BasePage class rather than from System.Web.UI.Page (basically just to provide common methods and custom properties) so what's the best-practice case here. Should we override Page_Load?
 Or call PushPromise() from somewhere else in the application?

Any assistance gratefully received. I know HTTP2 is fairly new, but I've found the lack of documentation/support/examples from Microsoft on this to be really poor.

Many thanks!

Comment: It seems like the best solution to this would actually be an Http Module that just watches requests and their usual follow-ups and somewhat-intelligently inserts PushPromise() calls for you, instead of having to write your own.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there is a "best practice" yet for new things such as this.  There is some documentation here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpresponsebase.pushpromise?view=netframework-4.7

This includes references to the specification.

I really don't know much about HTTP/2 but this seems like it would have some of the same rules that apply to headers, such as that you may not be able to push after a body has been sent, so your would likely have to issue the command during early stages of the pipeline.

Comment: Thanks Erik - that's the only documentation I could find as well but I think you'll agree that it's very bare bones? I agree that the same sort of rules that apply to headers are probably correct, but I've just been hoping that I'm not the first person to actually use this in the 'real world' and that there are some actual code examples floating around somewhere...?

Comment: @DanClarke - part of the problem is that HTTP/2 is not available for the vast majority of people, so there is less effort spent on documenting it.  Also, the implementation is not yet complete within the Microsoft ecosystem, so a lot of people are taking a "wait and see" approach.

Comment: I dunno Erik... Looking today, Caniuse have 81% of global users able to use http2 (http://caniuse.com/#search=http2) and KeyCDN say that by April this year they were serving 68% of their https requests over HTTP2 (https://www.keycdn.com/blog/http2-statistics/). It's not exactly niche anymore.

Comment: @DanClarke - I should have been more clear.  I was referring to .NET developers when I said "vast majority of people".  Most people are still using .NET 4.6 or 4.5.  And HTTP/2 is still poorly supported even in 4.7.

Answer (score 0):

Just to give an update on this: we initially tried to put PushPromise in the Page_Load() event of our BasePage class but we ran into some problems. We're not 100% sure it was this but the IIS worker process was crashing frequently after implementing it. There were a few other minor code changes at the same time and we rolled the whole lot back, but users with Chrome were also intermittently reporting ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR which would also seem to indicate this was the problem.

We're instead going to try and implement it in an HttpModule at Application_BeginRequest() so we'll see if that is more reliable.

Answer (score 0):

Technically you can do it wherever you send a response.

> The server creates the PUSH_PROMISE frame to the response part of a
>   normal, browser-initiated stream

Since you are calling on the response object ,you have to have Response object avaialble(in the context of a request which has an HTTP connection.

```
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.PushPromise("/Images/1.png");                  
        }
    }
```

I have done a channel 9 presentation on the basics of HTTP and all the benefits it gives [here](https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/Developer-Support-Series-PGI-Sessions/Developer-Support-Series-BuildvNext) .It also contains a demo of HTTP push promise with how it works in the network trace level.I also have a complete demo code here in [this github repo](https://github.com/bdotnet/http2-demo)